# Is there a holomorphic function at $z=0$ with $f(\frac{1}{n}) = f(-\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{10n+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a holomorphic function at $z=0$ with $f(\frac{1}{n}) = f(-\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{10n+1}$?

I think that function $f(z) = \frac{|z|}{10+|z|}$ may work, but I'm not sure. I guess I have to use identity priciple, but I can't do it properly.

Comment: That function satisfies the equation, but isn't holomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$g(z)=\frac z{10+z}$$
matches your $f$ for $z=1/n$. It's holomorphic at $0$.
If your $f$ is also holomorphic at $0$ then $f=g$ by the identity principle. But $g(-1/n)\ne f(-1/n)$. So there's no such $f$ holmorphic
at $0$.